# Multiple Lines from Multiple Data D3js

Tags: d3.js, svg, path, line

I would expect the following code to plot two different lines on the same svg but it only returns two empty path>

```
<body>

<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>

<script>

data = [
{ Name: "line1", color: "blue", Points: [{x:0, y:5 }, {x:25, y:7 }, {x:50, y:13}] },
{ Name: "line2", color: "green", Points: [{x:0, y:10}, {x:25, y:30}, {x:50, y:60}] }
];

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {return d.x})
  .y(function(d, i) {return d.y})

var lines = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", line);

</script>

</body>
```

I cannot find multiple line charts example that have a data structure similar to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing the whole object from your array of data to the `line()` function, which is expecting an array of points. One alternative is to change the calling function to pass in only the `Points` array, something like this (untested):

```
.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.Points); })
```

Comment: damn yes, I see, instead I was doing it with .attr("d", line(function(d) { return d.Points; }))

Answer (score 1):

In fact you need to access the Points field of each element of the data array:

Within:

```
var lines = d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", line);
```

replace

```
.data(data)
```

by

```
.data(data.map( function(d) { return d.Points }))
```